# Adding "Categorize" in the action tab of Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

How do you add *Categorize* to the action drop down?

My list of categories still exists but I had not used it since my last upgrade.

Comment: Lotus Notes is a product that comes with mail, calendar, todos, contacts and a lot of application templates by default. And almost all of these applications support categorization. As long as you don't explain, where you want to have the categories, nobody will be able to help you. This question is vague and hardly to understand and is missing the version number, as categorization might work differently in different versuons

Comment: Please come back and give us more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an eProductivity addon that allows categorization. I don't think the stock template has it beyond sorting calendaring items from high and normal categories.

Likely, you'll need to contact your Notes administrators.

Comment: This answer is not correct. To categorize calendar entries you do not need an administrator at all. This function exists by default.

Comment: I'm not sure you can say my answer is not correct without the OP clarifying if he's talking about mail, calendar or todo. It also depends on the mail template used. Ours is pretty stock and I don't have categories at all.

Comment: If your template IS original, then you HAVE categories, believe me. The fact, that you don't see them, can have multiple causes (e.g. They can be hidden using the calendar profile).

Comment: I was wrong, it is not in the Calendar Profile: Create a new calendar entry and click on "Display - Category"

Comment: Oh you're right, I do have them on calendar entries. I forgot it was there because I don't use it and it's easy to overlook the line for it.